# Simple Group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ and $K$ normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H$ and $K$ are simple, $G=HK$, and $H\cap K = \langle e \rangle$. Show that either

1. $H\cong K\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ a prime, or
2. The only normal subgroups of $G$ are $\langle e\rangle$, $H$, $K$, and $G$.

Comment: I really need help with this problem, have been stuggling with it for a long time. Thanks.

Comment: By "$H\cap K$ is the generator $e$," do you mean $H\cap K=\langle e\rangle$? (The first is nonsense, the second isn't. Also, almost always the letter $e$ is reserved for the *identity* element of a group, and it seems this is not the case here.) Where in the world does $N$ come from in your last sentence?

Comment: What is N? And you should really be more careful with the way you write: it's very hard to understand what you say...for example, it **seems* to be that $\,H\cap K=\{e\}\,$ , which means $\,H,K\,$ have trivial intersection...

Comment: I've edited your question for readability - can you verify that you meant what I've written?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Assuming Alex's effort is the correct answer: since $\,H\,,\,K\lhd G\,\,,\,\,H\cap K=1$ then their product is isomorphic with their *direct product*:

$$G=HK\cong H\times K$$

Thus *any* normal subgroup of $\,H\,$ or $\,K\,$ is normal in $\,G\,$ , and if $\,N\lhd G\,$ , then $\,N\cap K\lhd K\;,\;\;N\cap K\lhd K\,$ .

Complete now the argument.

Comment: Hi, yes the way you wrote the intersection of H and K is correct. Sorry for the confusion. The last part, I checked the question is correct. The N just suddently appear at the end, it says, if N is normal to G, then N = e (inside the diamond sign), H, K, or G.

Comment: Stop saying "e (inside the diamond sign)"...:) . In group theory we use to denote $\,\langle x\rangle\,$ the *cyclic* group generated by $\,x\,$...this is what is meant here.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for the hint, I know about the direct product part. But how you relate it to H is isomorphic to K and Zp? I thought if H and K are simple groups, then their order is either equal to G or identity? I assume identity is 1? I am new to abstract algebra.

Comment: Hahahha....I know the diamond sign is silly, but I was afraid I said it wrong. Ok then. I won't say it again =)

Comment: Well, *one* possibility is $\,H=K=\Bbb Z_p\,$ . Remember that any cyclic group of order a prime is trivially a simple group. the hint tries to help you to deal with the case when $\,H,K\,$ are NOT the cyclic group of order $\,p\,$...BTW, now that I read the editing of your question, there is one more possibility: that $\,H,K\,$ are cyclic group of order *different* primes. Check this...Did you take this question from some book?

Comment: Aside from the direct product, the book provides hint that elements in H commutes with elements in K. So is it means that HK is a subgroup of G? but I don't know if this can help to solve the Zp part.

Comment: The book doesn't says anything about different primes. Hmmm...do you think that is what the book says?

Comment: I think the book says different primes, because the intersection of H and K is the cyclic group generated by identity. Don't you agree? If H=K=Zp, then the intersection won't be that.

Comment: Oh, the can be *different*, though isomorphic, cyclic groups, @Lila...but I think I know what they mean here. I shall come back later with more since I must go now.